# Trouble building react-webapp with ESLint; ESLint couldn't find the config "developit" to extend from

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, eslint

My react app works as normal using `npm start`, but when I try `npm run build` I got trouble.

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 6.8.0.

ESLint couldn't find the config "developit" to extend from. Please check that the name of the config is correct.

The config "developit" was referenced from the config file in "/home/user/beregning-innsikt/beregning-innsikt-webapp/src/main/webapp/node_modules/@babel/preset-modules/package.json".

If you still have problems, please stop by https://gitter.im/eslint/eslint to chat with the team.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! beregning-innsikt-webapp@2.0.0 lint: `eslint 'src/**/*{.ts,.tsx}'`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the beregning-innsikt-webapp@2.0.0 lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2020-08-11T08_20_44_975Z-debug.log
ERROR: "lint" exited with 2.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! beregning-innsikt-webapp@2.0.0 prebuild: `npm-run-all clean lint && aurora-mi git`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the beregning-innsikt-webapp@2.0.0 prebuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2020-08-11T08_20_45_002Z-debug.log
```

The Babel config file contains this:

```
 "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "developit",
    "rules": {
      "no-console": 0,
      "new-cap": 0
    }
  },
```

I have tried node v 13.7.0 and 14.1.0.
Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

Seems like it is linting `node_modules` too

To fix this you can create file `.eslintignore` in your root directory and add `node_modules/` folder to your eslintignore file